# How to create type conditionals for functions that accept interface{} in go?

Tags: go

I'm writing a function that is meant to accept either strings or slices in go. However, when I type my parameters as `interface{}` I can't perform actions upon those variables even when inside a conditional which checks the type.

Can the compiler deduce that my local variable must be of type `Slice` once inside my `if` block? How can I accomplish a `for` loop over the `Slice` after I know for certain it is a Slice?

```
func createFields(keys interface{}, values interface{}) ([]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    fields := make([]map[string]interface{}, 1, 1)
    if reflect.TypeOf(keys).Kind() == reflect.Slice && reflect.TypeOf(values).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        if len(keys.([]interface{})) != len(values.([]interface{})) {
            return fields, errors.New("The number of keys and values must match")
        }
        // How can I loop over this slice inside the if block?
        for i, key := range keys.([]interface{}) {
            item := map[string]string{
                "fieldID":    keys[i], // ERROR: invalid operation: keys[i] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
                "fieldValue": values[i],
            }
            fields.append(item)// ERROR: fields.append undefined (type []map[string]interface {} has no field or method append)
        }

        return fields, _

    }

    if reflect.TypeOf(keys).Kind() == reflect.String && reflect.Typeof(values).Kind() == reflect.String {
        item := map[string]string{
            "fieldID":    keys,
            "fieldValue": values,
        }
        fields.append(item)
        return fields, _
    }

    return fields, errors.New("Parameter types did not match")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use type assertions like

```
keySlice := keys.([]interface{})
valSlice := values.([]interface{})
```

and work with those from that point onwards. You can even eliminate the use of `reflect`, like:

```
keySlice, keysIsSlice := keys.([]interface{})
valSlice, valuesIsSlice := values.([]interface{})

if (keysIsSlice && valuesIsSlice) {
    // work with keySlice, valSlice
    return
}

keyString, keysIsString := keys.(string)
valString, valuesIsString := values.(string)

if (keysIsString && valuesIsString) {
    // work with keyString, valString
    return
}

return errors.New("types don't match")
```

Or you can structure the whole thing as type switches:

```
switch k := keys.(type) {
case []interface{}:
    switch v := values.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        // work with k and v as slices
    default:
        // mismatch error
    }
case string:
    switch v := values.(type) {
    case string:
        // work with k and v as strings
    default:
        // mismatch error
    }
default:
    // unknown types error
}
```